# JavaScript working in Firefox but not other browsers

Tags: javascript

I am fiddling with this piece of code to try to understand how parts of it work.  Everything seems to be working as expected in Firefox, however the Login button does not work in any other browser.  When I inspect it in Chrome it is saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>
> at JSON.parse ()
>
> at CheckUsername (alt.html:24)
>
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (alt.html:72)

And before that it was complaining about the CookieVars variable being undefined (I think, I cannot get it to replicate that error again).

I have tried Googling the issue but some of the explanations are way over my head or seem to not be relevant to my situation.

Can someone tell me how come this works in Firefox and not any other browser?  What the issue is and how it can be fixed?

Your assistance is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script>
function NewMember() {
    var CookieVars = {};

    CookieVars.username = document.getElementById("UsersName").value;
    CookieVars.password = document.getElementById("PassWord").value;

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(CookieVars);

    document.cookie = "MembersDetails=" + jsonString;
    alert("Thank you, you are now registered.");
    ClearTextBoxes();
}

function CheckUsername() {
    var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
    var CookieVars = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);
    var UsersNameVar = document.getElementById("UsersName").value;

    if (CookieVars.username == UsersNameVar) {
       CheckPassword();
            } else {
                alert("Username not recognised, please register.");
    }
}

function CheckPassword() {
   var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
   var CookieVars = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);
   var PassWordVar = document.getElementById("PassWord").value;
   if (CookieVars.password == PassWordVar) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "You are now logged in, welcome.";
   } else {
      alert("Incorrect Password.");
   }
}

function ClearTextBoxes() {
    document.getElementById("UsersName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("PassWord").value = "";
}

</script>
<body>
  <table border="3">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Username:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="UsersName">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Password:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="PassWord">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="NewMember()">
        <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="CheckUsername()">
        <input type="button" value="Clear Boxes" onclick="ClearTextBoxes()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <p id="message"></p>
<img src="" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 99% of the time "Unexpected token u" means that you're trying to parse `undefined`. Which probably means that the cookie doesn't exists in any other browser than your Firefox.

Comment: according to the comment above this line `var CookieVars = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);` should produce the error. That means that nameValueArray[1] is `undefined` or hast got a value starting with `u`

Comment: How do I edit the code to get this to work in the other browsers and why does it work in Firefox?

Comment: print `nameValueArray` into the console and have a look at the values

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't support cookies for local files (or, like Peter Lyons mentioned, localhost*) unless you start it with the --enable-file-cookies flag. You can read a discussion about it at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535.*Chrome does support cookies if you use the local IP address (127.0.0.1) directly. so in the localhost case, that could be an easier workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Don, that explains why Opera does not run it either.  Is the lack of local cookie support the reason it does not work in Edge as well?

Answer (score 0):

validate your JSON:

```
function isJSON(str) {
    try {
        return (JSON.parse(str) && !!str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function CheckUsername() {
  var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
  var CookieVars = (nameValueArray && isJSON(nameValueArray[1])) ? JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]) : false;
  var UsersNameVar = document.getElementById("UsersName").value;

  if (CookieVars && CookieVars.username == UsersNameVar) {
   CheckPassword();
        } else {
            alert("Username not recognised, please register.");
  }
}

function CheckPassword() {
  var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
  var CookieVars = (nameValueArray && isJSON(nameValueArray[1])) ? JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]) : false;
  var PassWordVar = document.getElementById("PassWord").value;
  if (CookieVars && CookieVars.password == PassWordVar) {
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "You are now logged in, 
   welcome.";
 } else {
  alert("Incorrect Password.");
 }
}
```

this will prevent that error. But maybe there is still an error in your code which causes the wrong data to be written into `nameValueArray`. For example because of Chrome's Cookie behaviour.

greetings

Comment: Greetings to you to @messerbill.  Thank you for the extra code, I only started with JSON this morning so I shall need to go back and do some more research on it.